# Is there a better way to delegate enumeration?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, enumeration

I have the following code to hand enumeration over to a private field:

```
interface

type    

TMyClassEnumerator = class(TEnumerator<TMyClass>)
end;

TMyContainerClass = class(TObject)
private
  FItems: TObjectDictionary<string, TMyClass>;
public
  function GetEnumerator: TMyClassEnumerator;
end;

implementation

function TMyContainerClass.GetEnumerator: TMyClassEnumerator;
begin
  Result := TMyClassEnumerator(FItems.Values.GetEnumerator);
end;
```

Am I doing this right? I fought with implementing `IENumerable<TMyClass>` or creating my own interface, however, I got none of it to compile... The above code does work for example with `for..in`, but I feel I should make it a proper enumerable by implementing such interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is sound, but I don't see that you need to cast, or indeed declare an enumerator class. I'd do it like this:

```
TMyContainerClass = class
private
  FItems: TObjectDictionary<string, TMyClass>;
public
  function GetEnumerator: TEnumerator<TMyClass>;
end;

function TMyContainerClass.GetEnumerator: TEnumerator<TMyClass>;
begin
  Result := FItems.Values.GetEnumerator;
end;
```

Comment: Actually I had it like that at a moment, and wasn't sure if there's any real advantage to "typedeffing" it, which seems to happen quite a lot. When I did, the cast was necessary. Anyway, I can forget about implementing `IENumerable<TMyClass>`? Embarcadero recommends doing so rather than only supplying `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: Implement `IEnumerable<>` if you need to. If you want to support for/in iteration then the above is what you need. I absolutely would not declare an enumerator class. Just use `TEnumerator<TMyClass>`.

Comment: Can you show how to do that? My compiler was giving very ambiguous errors and every source I found uses a different set of hacks.

Comment: Implement `IENumerable<TMyClass>`.

Comment: That's a different question that has already been asked. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657475/implementing-list-enumerator-oftypet-in-delphi  In summary, it's a pain in the neck!

Comment: The IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T> definitions appear to shadow the .net equivalents. They are a disaster there too. It's all  because the original .net languages did not have generics. It's telling that there are no classes in the RTL that implement IEnumerable<T>!

Comment: Ambitious as I may be, as a beginning Delphi programmer I don't believe I need to do a better job than the designers of the RTL. So I'll keep it like this...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Actually the problem of the typed and untyped GetEnumerator methods is easily solved with interface mapping... (though I admit it took me a looooong time before realizing that).

Comment: @Marjan Yes, and then you have to implement the two interfaces.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: one liners... (IIRC might be two liners) I faced it because I wanted an interfaced version of TList<T>. But whether you wrap or inherit, the implementations do not need to keep you back... And with generics, you of course only need to do it once (pfew :-)).

Comment: @MarjanVenema It ought to be easy enough to write a single adapter from `TEnumerator<T: class>` to `IEnumerable<T>` and then just re-use that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: hmmm, need to think about what you are saying. Think I looked into that and ran into the fact that TList<T> has its own enumerator type, so inheritance was out. Can't recall the exact variations and design constraints at the time of the top of my head.

Comment: @MarjanVenema I think all the RTL enumerators are derived from `TEnumerator<T>`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, they do but you get "non-generic" enumerators back. TList<T>'s enumerator is declared as TEnumerator = class(TEnumerator<T>). Which means it is pretty hard to use them in a generic class of your own making (that uses and does not inherit from TList<T>). At least I had trouble doing so, but that may have been when I really just started out using generics. I'll revisit the issues and see what I can come up with using increased understanding of the stuff. Compiler error messages on generics unfortunately often are not very helpful.

Comment: @Marjan I think you can write a single adapter that adapts `TEnumerator<T>` to `IEnumerator<T>`.