# How many objecttypes are inside my objectlist

Tags: delphi

using an DELPHI object List I store references to Tforms class items. After creating and inserting forms to that list, also some delete  .... and other process steps are executed.
After I while It comes to that point where I need to evaluate the content of my objectlist.

```
  aForm1 : TMyForm_1 ;
  aForm2 : TMyForm_1 ;
  aForm3 : TMyForm_1 ;

  MyObjectList := TObjectList.create; 

  ....  
  MyObjectList.add(aForm1) ;  //  and also the other forms , many time each ...
```

How many instances of  forms from Type TMyform_1 are still in my list? 
Looping all list elements and checking the class type is my idea to solve that task

```
for i := 0 ....    
if (MyObjectList.items[i] is  TMyForm_1) ...
```

Any more elegant method to solve this issue ? 
Fist I need only to know is a TMyForm_1 type inside my list, second give me first position, and finally from this position ...  go to next element inside this list .

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using the legacy `TObjectList` rather than the typesafe generic `TObjectList<T>` or `TList<T>`?

Comment: I'm curious. Why would you have multiple instances of the same form in an object list?

Comment: @Andy_D I guess because it could be some edit form or something like that where you can edit multiple instances?

Comment: Note that your program already keeps a list of all forms in your program. See [`Screen.Forms`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.Forms).

Comment: @Andy It is quite routine to create multiple instances of a single type. Even for forms. Perhaps this is a common base type. Or perhaps these are MDI children.

Comment: Again, what is your final goal? Do you want do perform special actions to all the forms depending on the form type? Then there exist much better solutions to solve this, but you have to ask the right question ...

Comment: If you are using a Delphi version with generics you might consider this solution which might be what you want (filter by class): http://stackoverflow.com/a/10714941/587106

Answer (score 1):

`TObjectList` does not offer any methods that return information based on the runtime types of the members of the container. You have to write your own functionality using the `is` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant I can think of would be this:

```
uses
  Generics.Collections;

var
  dict: TDictionary<TClass,Integer>;
  obj: TObject;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // ...

  for obj in MyObjectList do
    if dict.TryGetValue(obj.ClassType, i) then
      dict[obj.ClassType] := i + 1
    else
      dict.Add(obj.ClassType, 1);

  // ...
end;
```

Comment: That doesn't really accomplish what was requested. According to the final paragraph, the first task is to determine *any* items of the given class exist in the list. This counts *how many* of each class there are, going through the entire list when it would have sufficed to stop at the first occurrence. This also categorizes by the leaf type of the class hierarchy, but the `is` operator checks all ancestor classes, too. The second task was to determine *which* item in the list matched the requested class, and the third task was to find the *next* item of that class; this code does neither.

Comment: He asked "How many instances of forms from Type TMyform_1 are still in my list?" The code he showed did the is operation. But actually my answer was referring to his requirements (the question) and not the code he showed. Maybe he should specify his requirements more clearly. As for the additional questions - I think that unless you want to create some ridiculous overhead looping through the list is fine so this does not require mentioning in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class helper for `TObjectList` and add a function that returns an array of items with the given type.

```
type
  TObjectListHelper = class helper for TObjectList
    function GetItemsByType<T : class> : TArray<T>;
  end;

  { TObjectListHelper }

function TObjectListHelper.GetItemsByType<T> : TArray<T>;
var
  LIdx : Integer;
  LItem : TObject;
  LCount : Integer;
begin
  SetLength( Result, Self.Count );
  LCount := 0;
  for LIdx := 0 to Self.Count - 1 do
  begin
    LItem := Self.Items[LIdx];

    if LItem is T then
    begin
      Result[LCount] := LItem as T;
      Inc( LCount );
    end;
  end;
  SetLength( Result, LCount );
end;
```

In your application you use it like this

```
var
  LItem : TMyForm_1;
begin
  for LItem in MyObjectList.GetItemsByType<TMyForm_1> do
  begin
    // do something with LItem
  end;
end;
```